# C# control size does not cover entire control

Tags: c#, controls

I've got a DataGridView with the RowHeaderVisible property set to false;

I have the margins and padding set to 0;

then the size is equal to the header widths added together...

Why is there extra space still needed to show the full control? (There is a horizontal scroll bar visible) What property does this, or how would you get an accurate measurement of the exact (actual) sizing of the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent used one for a while but if its like a listview, the headers should be less than the width to leave space for the vertical scrollbar - presuming you have one. Try reducing the width of one of the headers, or increasing the control width

Comment: yup, scroll bar width did it.

Comment: sort of, the headers + (SystemInfo.VerticalScrollbarWidth / 2) covered the datagridview problem, for the form you needed the whole width of the scrollbars.. wtf is going on?